# Once we load the page, inside the text box contain value 100. I need to show that value as animation like 0 to 100 using js.Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once we load the page, inside the text box contain value 100. I need to show that value as animation like 0 to 100 using js .Is this possible?

I develop code using span. But i can't develop inside textbox.

```
<span class="count">200</span>
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
         duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

I need same format(running animation) inside text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried below,

```js
$('.count').each(function() {

  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).val()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).val(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="100" class="count">
```

Comment: Its Working.. Thank you verymuch.